# Как писать тесты для строк?

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, тестирование, jest

У меня есть функция которая берет строку и проверяет является ли она CSS функцией `hsla`. CSS понимает разное написание этой функции — с тремя и четырьмя аргументами, без пробелов и с сотнями пробелов, а так же не понимает если нет знака процента у одного из трех аргументов.

Сейчас в тестах я учитываю все эти особенности, из-за чего код теста сильно раздувается:

```
test('Use hsl with wrong percentage placement', ()=>{
    expect(isHsl('hsl(360%, 100%, 100%)')).toBe(false);

    expect(isHsl('hsl(360, 100, 100%)')).toBe(false);
    expect(isHsl('hsl(360, 100%, 100)')).toBe(false);

    expect(isHsl('hsl(360, 100, 100)')).toBe(false);

    expect(isHsl('hsl(360, 100 %, 100)')).toBe(false);
    expect(isHsl('hsl(360, 100, 100 %)')).toBe(false);

    expect(isHsl('hsl(360, %100, 100)')).toBe(false);
    expect(isHsl('hsl(360, 100, %100)')).toBe(false);
});
```

Вот например тест на число пробелов который предлагает сомнительную пользу — все равно я не смогу проверить все возможные комбинации пробелов:

```
test('Check hsl with irregular spacing and get true', ()=>{
    expect(isHsl('hsl(12,1%,13%)')).toBe(true);
    expect(isHsl('hsl( 12 , 1% , 13% )')).toBe(true);
    expect(isHsl('hsl(  12  ,  1%  ,  13%  )')).toBe(true);
});
```

Ещё больше удручает то что я знаю что учел эти случаи в регулярных выражениях которые проверяют функцию и ошибки на этих местах быть точно не могут.

Как правильно тестировать такие функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Юнит-тесты нужны не для того, что бы проверять код. Они нужны для того, что бы контролировать изменения в коде и писать более качественный код за счёт просчитывания различных вариантов его использования. Поэтому Ваш подход вполне жизнеспособен. Если же у Вас есть время на более тщательное тестирование или ошибка в этой функции будет стоить слишком дорого, то можно воспользоваться следующими подходами:

**Техники тестирования белого ящика**. Все [подобные техники](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/white-box-testing-techniques-with-example/) основываются на покрытии кода. Т.е. мы пишем столько тестов, что бы при их выполнении выполнились все строчки/условия/выражения исходного кода. В случае регулярных выражений нужно сначала регулярку [превратить в конечный автомат](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/designing-finite-automata-from-regular-expression/).

**Фаззинг-тесты**. Для проведения подобных тестов нужно написать две функции. Одна будет генерировать радомные правильные строки, а вторая - неправильные. Такой подход приносит пользу, если число таких сгенерированных строк велико, а созданные функции генерируют максимально разнообразные строки.

**Боевые данные**. Правильные тестовые строки можно достать из существующих проектов на github или из ваших данных на продакшене, где в итоге будет использоваться тестируемая функция.

**Формальные методы**. В случае, если разрабатываемая Вами функция будет использоваться в космическом аппарате, медицинском оборудовании или на АЭС можно обратиться к [формальным методам тестирования](https://learntla.com/introduction/). В таком подходе разработка программ ведётся через формальное описание того **что** должна система делать, вместо описания того, **как** она это будет делать. После создания такого описания мы можем выполнить полную валидацию полученного решения.